# Numbering long chains of repeating values in a column of a table in PostgreSQL using window functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands, dense-rank

In PostgreSQL, I have a table with a column that has long repeats of 0's and 1's. I would like to create another column that ranks these with repeating ranks. Here is an example of what I'd like to see:

| Column | New column |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 0 | 3 |
| 0 | 3 |
| 0 | 3 |
| 0 | 3 |
| 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 0 | 5 |
| 0 | 5 |
| 0 | 5 |

and so on. Can the table functions with rank be used effectively to do this? Or is this something that is beyond the window function capabilities? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions; we can get the previous value with `lag`, then compute the window count of value changes to define the group each record belongs to.

Of course this requires a column to order the table, say `id`:

```
select id, col, 
  count(*) filter(where col is distinct from lag_col) over(order by id) grp
from (
    select t.*, lag(col) over(order by id) as lag_col
    from mytable t
) t
order by id
```

| id | col | grp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 |
| 6 | 1 | 2 |
| 7 | 1 | 2 |
| 8 | 0 | 3 |
| 9 | 0 | 3 |
| 10 | 0 | 3 |
| 11 | 0 | 3 |
| 12 | 0 | 3 |
| 13 | 1 | 4 |
| 14 | 1 | 4 |
| 15 | 0 | 5 |
| 16 | 0 | 5 |
| 17 | 0 | 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/q8YlHL4O)