# Numbering long chains of repeating values in a column of a table in Oracle using window functions

Tags: oracle, window-functions, gaps-and-islands, dense-rank

I have a similar question as: [Numbering long chains of repeating values in a column of a table in PostgreSQL using window functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76566598/numbering-long-chains-of-repeating-values-in-a-column-of-a-table-in-postgresql-u) , but then for Oracle.

So, I want to rewrite the following PostgreSQL sql to Oracle sql.

```
select id, col,    
  count(*) filter(where col is distinct from lag_col) over(order by id) grp 
from (     
    select t.*, lag(col) over(order by id) as lag_col     
    from mytable t 
) t order by id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT id, col, grp
FROM   mytable
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY id
  MEASURES MATCH_NUMBER() AS grp
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN  (same_col+)
  DEFINE   same_col AS FIRST(col) = col
);
```

Or, in earlier version you can use the `LAG` and `SUM` analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT id, col,
       SUM(has_changed) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS grp
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         CASE LAG(col) OVER (ORDER BY id) WHEN col THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS has_changed
  FROM   mytable t
) t
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytable (id, col) AS
SELECT  1, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  6, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  7, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  9, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 0 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| ID | COL | GRP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 |
| 6 | 1 | 2 |
| 7 | 0 | 3 |
| 8 | 0 | 3 |
| 9 | 1 | 4 |
| 10 | 0 | 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4nowGWLz)

*Note: the second method also works in PostgreSQL [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8BIcciAg).*